# Unable to execute cx_freeze built application

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I'm trying to produce a small `.exe` using `cx_freeze`. Earlier I had trouble with the build process in that it would not find certain self-created modules. I have now resolved that issue and I am no longer seeing those self-made modules in the `Missing modules` output after running `python setup.py bdist_msi`.

Instead, now after attempting to run the 'main.exe` that is produced I see:

```
ImportError No module named 'test'
```

My project structure is:

```
PROJECT
|
SRC
   |
   setup.py
   main.py
   test.py
   service.py
```

The `setup.py` is as follows:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None

if sys.platform == "Win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

includes = ["test", "service"] #discovered that self made modules, even in the same directory, had to be added here to not appear in the 'Missing modules'
excludes = []
packages = []
path = []

setup(
      name = "a thing", 
      version = "1.0",
      description = "a things description",
      author = "author",
      author_email = "authors email",
      url = "authors url",
      options = {"build_exe": {"includes": includes,
                               "excludes": excludes,
                               "packages": packages,
                               "path": path}
                 },
      executables = [Executable("main.py", base = base)]
  )
```

Comment: Try to import them in the setup.py module. I've seen that work before.

Comment: @JustinEngel thanks, tried that. Still the same error following build and execute. I don't get it, all the tutorials and guides (inc video guides) I've seen show what I have 'should' work. Totally confused.

Comment: If your main module imports test or service then you shouldn't have to include them at all. You may have to import main for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally you dont need to do any special treatment for your own modules.

i tried the following and for me it worked fine:
main.py:

```
from test import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mA=A()
    mA.b();
```

test.py:

```
class A:
    def b(self):
        print("test")
```

setup.py:

```
like yours  (without service.py)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: yes you are right. sorry. but until now i can not add comments to his post.

Comment: @der_die_das_jojo I tried changing from `includes` to `packages` and the same error, `ImportError: no module named 'test'`. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: @der_die_das_jojo Thanks for the updated answer. I've just recreated a simple example and it all works. For whatever reason, my original project is still stuck though. I'll keep trying and see what I can do.

Comment: Well I did resolve this eventually. I 'think' it was due to my true test.py actually being called api_test.py (I thought I should obfuscate my code as its for work rather than a personal project). Removing the underscore from the module name appears to have done the trick. No idea why. But hey, it builds, it installs, it executes.